# Regular expression for the name O`Malley, John F

Tags: python, regex

I am unable to generate a regular expression for the name **O`Malley, John F.**

Right now, I have the following.

re.compile(r'^[A-Z][a-z]+`, [A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+.$')

Any help or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just compare it with a normal string that just says "O`Malley, John F.", or is this just a format for the name?

Comment: It's the name format entered by the user for the input validation program.
The validator should accept this name( for that, need a regex pattern).

Comment: What is the logic behind whether or not a name is valid? People's names can be literally anything. There's not really any such thing as an "invalid" name. What is the purpose in "validating" a person's name? What is the purpose of this "validation" in relation to your program?

Comment: Acceptable inputs for name: 
• Bruce Schneier
• Schneier, Bruce
• Schneier, Bruce Wayne
• O’Malley, John F.
• John O’Malley-Smith
• Cher

So, I need to write a regex as the user will enter a name in form. To avoid any kind of bad inputs(malicious inputs for say SELECT * from db), need to accept only certain kind of names, And the above ones are acceptable formats. 

I have regex written for all the other inputs, except for the name: O’Malley, John F.

Comment: So I can't put my name into your program? Why not? Is there a specific set of users you're allowing to use your program? If so, why can't you just enumerate them?

Comment: The goal of this task is to produce a REST API that validates its input using regular 
expressions. @ddejohn

Comment: Per your edit, it looks like you are attempting to sanitize user input to protect from SQL injection. This is a losing battle. You should be using a database API.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that you literally cannot write regular expressions for every name there is.

Comment: I suggest maybe perusing this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861/sanitising-user-input-using-python

Answer (score 0):

For that specific name (format), the back tick is in the wrong place:

```
re.compile(r'^[A-Z]`{0,1}[a-z]+, [A-Z][a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]+.$')
```

You are asking for the regex for that specific name format, the above will catch a name with or without the back tick on the second position.

You should take into account the comments regarding the purpose of this exercise.